# Manifest not showing on Viewer

Tags: iiif

I have been going through the iiif workshop: https://ronallo.com/iiif-workshop/presentation/image-service.html

and managed to follow well till I needed to show my manifest on mirador or universal viewer. My json file is located on the localhost and if I try localhost/manifest.json the following comes up:

```
    {
    "@context": "http://iiif.io/api/presentation/2/context.json",
  "@type": "sc:Manifest",
  "@id": "http://localhost/manifest.json",
  "label": "Papillons",
  "description": "Four patterns inspired by butterflies.",
  "attribution": "Special Collections Research Center at NCSU Libraries",
  "sequences": [
    {
      "@type": "sc:Sequence",
      "canvases": [
        {
          "@type": "sc:Canvas",
          "@id": "http://localhost/segPap_022/canvas/1",
          "label": "22",
          "width": 6099,
          "height": 8599,
          "images": [
            {
              "@type": "oa:Annotation",
              "motivation": "sc:painting",
              "on": "http://localhost/segPap_022/canvas/1",
              "resource": {
                "@type": "dctypes:Image",
                "@id": "https://iiif.lib.ncsu.edu/iiif/segPap_022/full/500,/0/default.jpg",

                "service": {
                  "@context":  "http://iiif.io/api/image/2/context.json",
                  "@id": "https://iiif.lib.ncsu.edu/iiif/segPap_022",
                  "profile": "http://iiif.io/api/image/2/level2.json"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Any idea why it is not being rendered on the viewers? Am I doing something wrong? I even created the folder structure for the canvases on the web server

Comment: What Mirador / UniversalViewer instances do you use? Local ones or the public demos? For the letter, you will run into CORS and mixed content issues. Does the Browser console provide any errors?

Comment: You will also get CORS errors if you have your local viewer on another port than 80 and your web server on localhost does not provide the necessary `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: I am using the demo one...do you think I should download a local mirador?

Comment: The Mirador demo site enforces https, so you will not get around the mixed content issue with http://localhost. As for the universal viewer, you could try to set a suitable `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. For Apache, it's done with `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` in the site's config. See https://enable-cors.org/ . A local Mirador served from the localhost webserver would require a npm build. Maybe try to set the HTTP header first.

Comment: So I tried to see what the console errors are. For mirador I am getting the warning for mixed content but for universalviewer I am getting these 2 errors: 'TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function
jquery.js:9857:13
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data'

Comment: I think you can ignore the jquery error for now; as for the json error: remove all whitespaces before the first `{`.